# Allow employees to login after "Why you need your phone"

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Our employee is unable to access their Gmail account. I'm going to retype this whole error from a screenshot.

> We detected an unusual sign-in attempt. To make sure that someone else isn't trying to access your account, your organization needs you to sign in using your corporate mobile device (the phone or tablet you normally use to access your corporate account).
>
> If you don't have your corporate mobile device with you right now, try again later when you have your corporate mobile device with you. If you continue to ave problems signing in, contact your administrator. Learn more
>
> Go back & use your corporate mobile device

[image]

The only way I can get this person to login is to activate

> Login challenge
>
> TURN OFF FOR 10 MINS
>
> Turn off identity questions for 10 minutes after a suspicious attempt to sign in. Learn more
> Disabling login challenge will make the account less secure

This is getting old fast because the employee wants to work from home on their own schedule. And every time they want to login I need to access that page to allow them to login for 10 minutes.

How can I have them login as normal like every other account?